# append method to jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i write this plugin and now i want add method to this plugin such as this

$.createMessage().removeMessage()

how can i do it?

my code is

```
$(function () {

    $.extend({

        createtext: function (options) {

            var setting = {
                holder: "",
                text: "",
            }

            if (options != null) {
                $.extend(setting, options)
            }

            var $this = $(setting.holder)

            $this.find("div#CreatetextHolder").remove()


            $this.append("<div id='CreatetextHolder'><span></span><p class='Createtext'>" + setting.text + "</p></div>")

            $this.find("div#CreatetextHolder").fadeIn('slow')

        }

    })
})
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(selector).createMessage().removeMessage()` would require you to write two plugins - one for 'create' and the other for 'remove'.

It's far better to do everything in one plugin and you can do so by targeting the syntax ...

```
$(selector).createMessage('remove');
```

Then it's a matter of testing `options` in the plugin code, and branching accordingly.

Currently you test `if (options != null)` assuming `options` to be a javascript plain object and that the only action is initianisation.

But with my suggestion to allow `$.createMessage('remove')`, you need to perform more extensive testing/branching depending on what parameter(s) are actually passed.

For example:

```
$(function () {
    $.extend({
        createtext: function ( method, options ) {
            var settings = {
                holder: "",
                text: ""
            };
            var methods = {
                'init': function(options) {
                    var _settings = $.extend({}, settings, options);//this leaves `settings` unaffected and available for reuse in future inits.
                    //initialize here
                },
                'remove': function() {
                    //uninitialize here
                }
            }

            // These tests allow `init' to be passed explicitly, 
            // or assumed if an options object is the only argument.
            // Otherwise, a method such as 'remove' may be passed, 
            // with or without further parameters.
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.createtext');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help, how i can add this option into my coed ? $(selector).createMessage('remove'); ?

Comment: I just added an extra line with a comment, to show you how to `extend` the settings. Done the wrong way, you will overwrite the default `settings`.